# Need help. Basic HTML/CSS. Headers not changing color

Tags: html, css, colors, header, css-selectors

I need help. I'm just starting CSS/HTML and I was able to change the color of a pages header1 content in a website with css before. Now i've tried the exact same lines of code and it stays flat black.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="pacific.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
<div id="nav"><b>
<a href ="index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href ="yurts.html">Yurts</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href ="activities.html">Activities</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href ="reservations.html">Reservations</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</b></div>
<div id ="content">
<h2>Enjoy Nature In Luxury</h2>
<p><span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special lodging experience on the California North Coast.Relax 
in sereninty with panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean.</p>
<ul>
<li>Private yurts with decks overlooking the ocean
<li>Activities lodge with fireplace and gift shop
<li>Nightly fine dining at the Overlook Cafe
<li>Heated outdoor pool and whirlpool
<li>Guided hiking tours of the redwoods
</ul>
<div id="contact">
<span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span>
<br>12010 Pacific Trails Road
<br>Zephyr, CA 95555
<br>
<br>888-555-5555
</div>
<div id="contact"><small><i>
Copyright &copy; 2011 Pacific Trails Resort
<br><a href= "mailto:nathan@griffin.com"> nathan@griffin.com</a>
</i></small></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS file.(validated on w3 website)

```
body{
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;}
h1{
    color: #000033;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 0;}
nav{
    background-color: #90c7e3;}
h2{
    color: #3399cc;}
dt{
    color: #000033;}
.resort{
    color: #000033;}
```

Can someone please point me to where I'm going wrong

Comment: Are you sure? `color: #000033;` is very dark, change it to something obvious like `color: #FF0000;` and its red as expected for me

Comment: you are missing hash before `nav` => `#nav` in your css, as you're using `<div id="nav"` in your html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
nav { ... }
```

To:

```
#nav { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine to me.

Note that you're setting it to `#000033`, which is a very dark blue (which is applied correctly, but might be missed because it's similar to black).

When I arbitrarily changed it to a different color (namely, `#BADA55`), it still works fine and is more visible.